# Html.ActionLink in a button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I Am trying to connect to a method in my controller, with a button. I can connect though this link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Print", "Print", new { id = Model.SalesContractId})
```

But i Don't want a link, i want my button on my dialog to do it. I have tried the following:

```
$('#btnDialogPrint').click(function () {
        location.href = '<%= Url.Action("Print", "Print", new { id = Model.SalesContractId}) %>'; 

    });
```

But it just redirect me to a page that say bad request.

```
namespace Contract.Controllers
{

    public class ContractController : Controller
    {

        CompassEntities db = new CompassEntities();

        public ActionResult Print(int id)
        {
            return View(""); // This can be removed and Print code may be added
        }
```

Don't worry about the code inside i will get to that once i get inside this method.

Could i maybe attach a link here?

```
<input type="button" value="Print" id="btnDialogPrint" />
```

**My View Edit.cshtml**

```
@model Contract.Models.tbSalesContract
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit Contract</title>
</head>
<!-- Script section -->
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Views/Contract.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Templates -->
<script id="tmplDebtorList" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">    
    <div class="DebtorResults">
    <span><div style="width:80px;float:left;">${CustomerAccNo}</div></span><span><a href="#" class="debtorLink" value="${DebtorId}">${CustomerName}</a></span>
    </div>
</script>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Contract", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmMain",name="frmMain" }))
    {
```

Comment: I think you should be doing an AJAX get in the event handler!

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Print","Contract", new {id = Model.SalesContractId})'
        }); This does not work ether

Comment: @daveL Could you please look at my ajax event and show me what im doing wrong

Comment: you are ignoring the return results.. have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what i was looking for, But thanks all.

```
$('#btnDialogPrint').click(function () {
       window.location = '../Print/' + $('#SalesContractId').val();
    });
```

Comment: Then you need to set this as the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Your link in the jQuery doesn't match the `ActionLink` link. Also, when using `Url.Action` don't specify the word `Controller`, it'll put that in for you.

**Edit: After seeing your edited post, you aren't using the correct controller.**

Try this:

```
$('#btnDialogPrint').click(function () {
    location.href = '<%= Url.Action("Print", "Contract", new { id = Model.SalesContractId}) %>'; 
});
```

**Edit2: I know the problem!** You're mixing Razor syntax with web forms syntax! Try this:

```
$('#btnDialogPrint').click(function () {
    location.href = '@Url.Action("Print", "Contract", new { id = Model.SalesContractId})'; 
});
```

**Another problem is the fact that you're trying to do this inside a JavaScript file, you cannot use Razor syntax in a JavaScript file it HAS to be in a View**

Answer (score 3):

Pomster; you've mixed up Razor and aspx..

use @Url.Action("Print", "Contract", new { id = Model.SalesContractId}) to create your link i.e

```
$('#btnDialogPrint').click(function () {
        location.href = '@Url.Action("Print", "Contract", new { id = Model.SalesContractId})';

    });
```

Where else have you done this?

Also your controller is Contract not Print

Comment: It says, Illegal characters in path.

Comment: you've got me confused anyway... is this page to be rendered by the razor engine or the aspx engine?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Razor in one code snippet and asp in the next. Is this intentional?

Assuming you simply want to call the controller:

First try changing the following in your code:

```
$('#btnDialogPrint').click(function () {
        location.href = '@Url.Action("Print", "Contract", new { id = Model.SalesContractId})'; 

    });
```

or

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Print", "Contract", new { id = Model.SalesContractId})%>
```

Otherwise:

Use Ajax:

In body:

```
<input type="button" value="Print" id="btnDialogPrint" onclick="print()"/>
```

In script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function print() {
            $.get('@Url.Action("Print", "Contract", new { id = Model.SalesContractId})');
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Just adding <input type="button" value="Print" id="btnDialogPrint" onclick="print()'/> and my code does not compile

Comment: Sorry i'm still writing the post. It will be updated in a min.

Comment: Just check you " and ' , i'm new to js so won't know the errors, but i can see you end you <unput type .... with a ' and all others are "

Comment: My bad. onclick="print()' should have been onclick="print()".

Comment: +1 Ok your code take me to a print screen, thanks, but you took me to the end and skiped the middle my print method is going to be in my controller.

Comment: Then you have routing issues. Do you have more than 1 view named print?

Comment: I think you need to set the controller as Contract? I have edited the post above.

Comment: I have a public ActionResult Print(int id), no views named print, my views are edit ad index

Comment: try: $.get('<%= Url.Action("Print", "Contract", new { id = Model.SalesContractId})%>'); instead.

Comment: Did you put it in a script block?